# Split the Json File which contains arrays to store each array in Sql Table using Azure Data flow

Tags: json, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a Json file which contains 5 arrays how can I split the arrays and store each array in particular sql table using Azure Data flow or Data Factory .My output should contain 5 tables in sql database i.e. data pertaining to each array in each table

Comment: Do the names of the array correspond to the name of the tables? Can you show us some snippets of your json file with fake data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple test.

This is my source json file:

```js
{
"emps": [{"name":"Tom","age":28},{"name":"Steve","age":25}],
"students": [{"name":"John","age":16},{"name":"Jason","age":15}]
}
```

1. Set json dateset to the source json file. In ADF dataflow, we can see the data preview is as follows:
   [image]
2. At `Select1` activity, we can only select `emps` column.
   [image]
3. Then we can flatten the json array at `Flatten1` activity.
   [image]
   The data preview is as follows:
   [image]
4. We can add a mapping to the Azure SQL table manually at `sink1` activity.
   [image]
5. Click `+` at source1 and add a new branch via select `New branch`. Then the same operations above.
   [image]
6. In the end we can split the arrays and copy into Azure SQL.
   [image]